# Failed to insert date into database with php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I had failed to insert the date values into database. It always shown me `"0000-00-00"`, which my date structure I set is date and it was a `"yyyy-mm-dd"`. I had try to debug my query and everything is okay except the date values can't insert into the database. Is there any mistake i had made on my code?

Here is my code:

```
$from = $_POST['from'];

$newFrom = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($from));
// Get default database object
$db = JFactory::getDBO();

// Get a new JDatabaseQuery object
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$tmpIds = array();

foreach($courseID as $cId) {
    $tmpIds[] = $db->quote($cId);
    //sanitize the input
}

$courseID1 = implode(',',$tmpIds);

// Build the query
$query->select($db->quoteName('courseid'));
$query->from($db->quoteName('intake'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('campusid').'='. $db->quote($campusID));

$query->where($db->quoteName('courseid').'IN('.$courseID1.')');

// Set the query for the DB oject to execute
$db->setQuery($query);
// Get the DB object to load the results as a list of objects
$results = $db->loadObjectList(); 

if($results){

    $query = "UPDATE intake SET startdate = $newFrom WHERE campusid = '$campusID'";
    echo "$query";
    $db->setQuery( $query );
    $db->query();

}

else{ echo 'Error';}

}
```

Comment: What is the type of the field 'startdate' in your DB?

Comment: Wrap your variable in quotes `SET startdate = '$newFrom'` since you're dealing with strings.

Comment: @Fred-ii- This time I was a bit faster! ;)

Comment: I was reaching for my cup of coffee @JohnConde +1 ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing quotes around your date string:

```
$query = "UPDATE intake SET startdate = $newFrom WHERE campusid = '$campusID'";
```

should be:

```
$query = "UPDATE intake SET startdate = '$newFrom' WHERE campusid = '$campusID'";
```

Comment: I pressed "Enter" in my comment just as this appeared ;-)

Comment: If the field in the db is of type DAte/Time its not necessary

Comment: Oh yes it is necessary @pc-shooter we're dealing with a string and not an integer. Otherwise, it will be interpreted as a math equation. `Y-m-d` - Year minus month, minus day.

Comment: @Fred -ii You're right.... it's because most of the time I save just timestamps... but hasn't this question already been answered many times?

Comment: Thanks guy, it work now. I was so dumb that make this kind of silly mistake >.<

Comment: @pc-shooter (Unix) Timestamps have no hyphens, only numbers, so you would've been theoretically correct. ;-)